# How to mount external directory in kubernetes service?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

How to mount external directory in kubernetes service like docker `-v /host/directory:/container/directory`?
Or how access from remote pc to volume in kubernetes service ?

P.S.: My case :
I am developing an interpreted program such as a node.js program. I want to use the editor/IDE on my desktop. But I want to run the program in a pod because it relies on things that exist in the kubernetes environment, and not my desktop (e.g. DNS, service account credentials, services, more memory/cpu, etc). I want to avoid the step of rebuilding an image and restarting a pod every time I make an edit.

Some answer here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18007

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the **hostpath** to mount the dir. from your host system. here is the sample from the doc.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#example-pod-1

Comment: I want this directory to be next to the pod on the node where the pod will be deployed.
I want to create an pod, tie a storage to it or mount a directory and location the mounted directory next to the pod. And get **access to volume from my PC** via ssh.

Comment: HostPath tied local to the container host, we can't move the pod to different host. based on your docker example I suggested this answer.  if your looking to schedule pod on any container node. you need to select NFS, or other supported storage from the above document.